# How to change the orientation of BottomSheet when Activity In Landscape Mode?

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

My activity is constrained to landscape mode. I have a `BottomSheet` in that `Activity`. When I change the device orientation I need to change the `BottomSheet` orientation from portrait to landscape and vice versa. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Does your `Activity` rotates too? Or the `Activity` orientation is fixed to landscape.

Comment: Yeah!!! right@ReazMurshed  does you `Activity` rotates?

Comment: Activity always in landscape mode.